# GIT: How to remove file from master and put in other branch?

Tags: git

I accidently added and comitted file in `master` instead of `mybranch` branch. Now even I switch to `mybranch` I can't see it by doing `git status`. How do make that file appear again for adding/committing and re-add in `mybranch`?

Comment: Is the file created and added only in one commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rebase this commit in your `mybranch`

First, fix `master` branch

```
git checkout master
git branch tmp   // This creates a branch in the "wrong" commit
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

You move your `master` branch one commit back. You still have a temporal branch pointing to your commit.

Now, Move the commit to `mybranch` branch

```
git checkout tmp
git rebase --onto mybranch master tmp
git checkout mybranch
git merge tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

The rebase command:

- The starting point: --onto mybranch
- From what commit: master
- to what commit: tmp

I recommend you to open some frontend to see what you are doing. I use `gitk`

```
gitk --all &
```

Answer (score 0):

In the master branch use `git rm dir1/dir2/file`. In the correct branch use `git show master:dir1/dir2/file >dir1/dir2/file` and `git add dir1/dir2/file`

If you have updated the master branch after the wrong commit, of course you cannot use `master` in the `git show` command to get the files back. You can use `git reflog` to find a suitable reference. If it happens to be `HEAD@{2}` the command will be `git show HEAD@{2}:dir1/dir2/file >dir1/dir2/file`

(git will automatically recognize that it is the same file contents, so you don't have to be worried about double disk space consumption.)

Comment: `master` has already been `stashed` so it's clear. Issue is that all local changes got removed.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean the by "master has been stashed". You wrote the wrong files had already been committed, so you can get them back by git show. I added more instructions in case you have updated your master branch since (e.g. to revert the commit or committed the file removal)

Comment: Look, I wrote code and accidently added in `master`. Now I have created a branch and reset the `master` by running `git stash`, which removed files from master. The changed file are already in `mybranch`

Comment: Git reset and git stash are different commands. In the original question you wrote you committed the wrong files, in the last comment you mention only adding. Again, these are different commands. You should edit your question to write a clear and complete sequence of relevant commands you gave (E.g.  1.) add 2.) commit. 3.) reset 4.) checkout, ... whatever it was) and then describe what you still want to achieve. git show with a reference from the reflog should also be suitable after git reset. git show works also from the stash, e.g. gitk will display the reference or sha1 to use.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491). You can use `rebase -onto` or `cherry-pick`. As for me - I prefer `cherry-pick`.